# Highlighted content web-part should show data based on current logged in user's location

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, events, kql, highlighted-content-web-part

I want a webpart that shows Events/Holidays based on the current user's location.

I'm using the Highlighted Content web part. I've filtered only on `ContentType:Events` and scope is on whole site.

How can I filter the events to only show events/holidays for the location by the current user (the person viewing the webpart)? The events have been tagged with different countries.

To get the current user name, there is attribute `user.name`. Is there anything similar to get the  current user's location e.g. `user.Location` or `user.Country`?

Answer (score 0):

Using graph api you can get current login user's office location and country details.

Based on it you can filter the holiday and event list in web part.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "businessPhones": [
        "+1 412 555 0109"
    ],
    "displayName": "Megan Bowen",
    "givenName": "Megan",
    "jobTitle": "Auditor",
    "mail": "MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com",
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": "12/1110",
    "preferredLanguage": "en-US",
    "surname": "Bowen",
    "userPrincipalName": "MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com",
    "id": "48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038"
}


GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "id": "48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038",
    "deletedDateTime": null,
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "ageGroup": null,
    "businessPhones": [
        "+1 412 555 0109"
    ],
    "city": "Pittsburgh",
    "createdDateTime": "2017-07-29T03:07:25Z",
    "creationType": null,
    "companyName": null,
    "consentProvidedForMinor": null,
    "country": "United States",
    "department": "Finance",
    "displayName": "Megan Bowen",
    "employeeId": null,
    "employeeHireDate": null,
    "employeeType": null,
    "faxNumber": null,
    "givenName": "Megan",
    ....
}
```