# Highlighted content web part filter crawled property based on user profile attribute

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search, user-profile-property, highlighted-content-web-part

I want the Highlighted content webpart to display news items filtered on RefinableString00 with the user.officeLocation.

The news pages have a sitecolumn with data (text) that's crawled & managed and connected to RefinableString00.
I can see that the metadata is available with the SharePoint Search Query Tool:

[image: Search displays refiablestring00]

I can see that the user profile contains the correct value via the GraphAPI:
[image: User.officeLocation contains the same value]

But I can't get the Highlighted content web part to filter based on the user profile. It does work when I hardcode "ITNews" in it. But whatever I do, the user profile options don't display anything.
[image: Different filter options I tried]

---

### **Is it possible to filter based on the user profile? If so, what am I doing wrong? I'm feeling that I'm really close in getting it to work.**

---

*I've found the following resources that got me this far:

1. [Highlighted content web-part should show data based on current logged in user's location](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/300317/highlighted-content-web-part-should-show-data-based-on-current-logged-in-users)
2. https://www.sharepointeurope.com/filter-a-content-search-webpart-by-a-user-profile-property/
3. [SmartCAML](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NN8GJPNXVFG)
4. [SharePoint Search Query Tool](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/SharePoint.Search.QueryTool)*

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your scenario and it seems that Highlighted web part does not support filter based on user profile property i.e. **{ManagedPropertyName}:{User.{UserProfilePropertyName}}**. However it's working when calling Search API.

Here best approach to use [PnP Search](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/) Result Web Part where you can use below query which will give you expected result. PnP Search Result web part does also have similar design template.

```
RefinableString00:{User.SPS-Location}
```

Comment: I wondered where you found SPS-Location. After some digging I found that the User profile is synced via the user profiles and displayname "Office location" is indeed crawled with the user profile attribute "SPS-Location" (See: SharePoint admin portal - Mote Features - User Profiles -  "Office Location").

After that I could get the Highlighted content webpart to display the correct news by setting it to "Custom query" and the following in the Query text:
RefinableString00:{User.SPS-Office}