# Utilizing Office 365 User Properties in SharePoint List Views Filter

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, office-365, list-view, modern-experience

Is there a way to utilize Office 365 User properties in the SharePoint list views filter?

In our organization's O365 User collection, we have the property 'Department'. I would like to know if it can be used in a view's filter (shown below).

[image]

I usually use it in Power Apps and helps me use and move data around with flexibility but I'm not sure if it's even feasible with just SharePoint.

[image]

Comment: Hi @badsalvarado, does my below response help you in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to filter SharePoint list views using Office 365 user profile properties.

You can only filter person or group columns based on `[Me]` but you cannot use other user profile properties to filter SharePoint online list views.

---

**Additional**:

You may be able to filter list items in Highlighted web part based on user profile properties but the look and feel of highlighted web part is very different from default SharePoint list views. Also, you cannot customize the display of highlighted content web part currently.

Check: [Highlighted content web part filter crawled property based on user profile attribute](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305104/highlighted-content-web-part-filter-crawled-property-based-on-user-profile-attri)

Answer (score 0):

You can harness Office 365 User properties to filter SharePoint list views. Let me walk you through the process with some practical code examples.

Firstly, open the SharePoint list you wish to filter. Ensure you are working within the specific list you want to customize, and create a view that you'll enhance with tailored filters.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
```

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("Your_Site_URL");
```

```
List targetList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Your_List_Name");
View targetView = targetList.Views.GetByTitle("Your_Target_View");
```

Next, navigate to the view you want to enhance. You can choose the default "All Items" view or any other existing view where you'd like to implement your customized filters.

```
targetView.ViewFields.Add("Title");  // Add fields you want to display
targetView.ViewFields.Add("Department");  // Office 365 User property
```

```
targetView.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Once you've located your target view, click the "Modify view" button. This step is crucial to enable modifications to the view settings and filter options. You'll define the rules for your filters here.

```
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = @"<View>
<Query>
<Where>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name='Department'/>
<Value Type='Text'>Your_Department</Value>
</Eq>
</Where>
</Query>
</View>";
```

```
targetView.Query = query;
targetView.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Now, you're ready to create filters tailored to your specific needs, enhancing your SharePoint list views with Office 365 User property-based criteria. This code enables you to seamlessly integrate user properties with your list views, providing valuable customization for your data organization.

Comment: Thank you, will definitely give this one a go.